# How to use custom parquet compression algorithm?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, parquet

Is it possible to use a customized compression algorithm in Spark to read and write on Parquet files?

Ideally, it would be configured as follows:

```
sqlContext.setConf("spark.sql.parquet.compression.codec", "myalgo")
```

Answer (score 4):

No, as stated [in the documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/sql-programming-guide.html#configuration) (here referring to version 2.2.0) the only acceptable values are

- `uncompressed`,
- `snappy`,
- `gzip` and
- `lzo`

with `snappy` being the default one.

This is due to a limitation of Parquet itself, which only uses a restricted set of compression algorithms, as listed in [this enumeration](https://github.com/apache/parquet-mr/blob/parquet-1.5.0/parquet-hadoop/src/main/java/parquet/hadoop/metadata/CompressionCodecName.java#L22-L25) (valid for version 1.5.0).

Comment: Also newer Parquet versions support Brotli and ZStandard as compression algorithms. But these then can be read by newer Parquet readers (I don‘t think any of the typical Hadoop distributions support this yet)

Comment: @UweL.Korn  Is `brotli` supported by spark yet (nearly 5 years later)

Comment: Probably it is but I would recommend nowadays to use ZSTD instead. It should be available in all recent Parquet releases/implementations and is probably superior in all aspects to Brotli.